# Узнать размер расширения для Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, extension, filesize

Я иногда уезжаю в места с очень плохим Интернетом, и бывает приходится устанавливать расширения для VS Code.

И когда я устанавливаю расширение, то хочется узнать его вес, т.к. когда скачиваю большой файл, остальные программы на компьютере начинают плохо работать...

Итак, есть ли способ всё-таки узнать размер расширения?

Comment: 1. скачать и посмотреть. 2. может быть указан на странице скачивания. 3. после начала скачивания браузер обычно показывает общий размер файла (но случается, что и не показывает)

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что установка расширений происходит в самом VS Code... И почему-то у них не указан размер

Comment: тогда предварительно сходить на тот сайт, откуда они скачиваются. Мож там размер указан.

Comment: Они скачиваются с гитхаба, но там тоже не указано

Comment: дай ссылку на какое-нибудь

Comment: Вот, например: github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server

Comment: Знаю, что оно небольшое, но если попадется большое...

Comment: а что именно скачивается? исходники?

Comment: Скачивается, получается исходники, но это по факту представляет собой само расширение

Comment: тогда как вариант можно нажать на зеленую кнопку со словом Code и скачать зип. А так общий размер репозитория вряд ли узнаешь, не скачав, там же куча файлов.

Comment: Да, получается так... Ещё посмотрю, вроде был способ узнать размер самого репозитория

Answer (score 2):

Кликаете по названию расширения, открываете его страничку на сайте майкрософта ([пример](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph)).

Там нажимаете <kbd>Download Extension</kbd> и получаете .vsix-файл для офлайн-установки расширения. Смотрите на его вес.